# UIImageView does not update in a thread made by NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, objective-c-blocks

I do a connection to server using Async connection this way:

```
// Create the request.
    [indicator startAnimating];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",MY_URL,@"testvalue"]]];        
    // Create url connection and fire request
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    //[self getJsonFromURL:resultLabel.text];
```

Then after the connection succeeded to get the response. I try to set the image to image view
Here i tried all the possibilities

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
    //[resultImage setImage:img];
    resultImage.image = img;
});
//[resultImage setImage:img];
//resultImage.image = img;
resultLabel.text = label;
[indicator stopAnimating];
```

Regarding that setting the label works well, as well as stopping the indicator work well even though from outside the main thread.

Comment: Do you have correct `image`? Check if its not `nil` by putting debugger point.

Comment: Is this connection not on the `main thread`? If it is, you dont need `dispatch_async` for setting the `resultImage` to image. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @iphonic Yes I tried correct image and i tried to load local image file.

Comment: @AbhishekBedi I commented some code which I also tried, I tried to set the image without dispatch_async.. I gave the dispatch_async a try i thought it could be the trouble.

Comment: Can you try `NSLog(@"img = %@", img);` in the dispatch async and put the log here?

Comment: resultImage.layer.cornerRadius = resulImage.frame.size.width / 2;
resultImage.clipsToBounds = YES;      //on the already loaded image, it works to make the border circular

Comment: @3329 that code from this page http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-circular-image-calayer/

Comment: @MBH I think I may be missing something here. Is it related to your problem ?

Comment: @3329 I set image inside my imageView from StoryBoard, I edited the border of the imageView without changing the image, It worked. I mean editing the imageView works well, but changing the image does not work.

Comment: Yes, I works. What I think is that the `image` is wrong, it may be nil. (PS: I've tried the code from appcoda, it worked and I could also change the image too.)

Comment: NSLog(@"img = %@", img); I tried this and it gives me (null). I creat the image like this, img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"qr_ic.png"];

Comment: @MBH You should use the full path instead of just the filename or use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"qr_ic.png"]` instead. And you should check your app bundle if it actually included the image.

Answer (score 1):

I also think the image might be nil, just save it to the filesystem and check it with an external image viewer:

```
NSString *docFolder = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingString: @"/"];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@image.png", docFolder];
[data writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];
```

Comment: In the code I put in the question, I used image downloaded from internet. I also tried with local image file. It does the same and nothing appear. Even if there is already another image in the UIImageView, when I try to set the image, the old image is gone!